# Why is the Charts module not working for anonymous visitors?

Tags: views, commerce, hooks

I'm using the [Charts](https://www.drupal.org/project/charts) module in my project. I've configured Google Chart in my custom view which needs to be shown to anonymous users. The view is shown, but the chart is not rendered for anonymous users.

> [image: screenshot]

It is shown for logged-in users.

> [image: screenshot]

Acquia is used. For Graph chart, I've used the storage and feed module.

I changed the view permission to unrestricted and changed the module permission to "allowed for anonymous users" but the chart is still not rendered.

Comment: try to set view permission for Unrestricted. check if you need to set any permission on chart module or acquia, because de graph data could be accessible only for some roles

Comment: @Pedro I've checked with these two changes. 1. set the view permission for unrestricted 2. Set  all the user roles including anonymous user for this chart module. But didn't work.

Comment: have you get any error on developer console and also drupal log register?
the graph is being loaded but not data? or neither graph is being loaded?
access to that page on a incognito window, and then check drupal logs, and let us know what the error/warning is it

Comment: Browser console is clean and no error was found in watchdog.

Comment: @Pedro I observe with login template_preprocess_charts_chart hook gets called. without logged in it doesn't.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP reported this as a bug on the module. This can’t be both a bug and a question we can answer. https://www.drupal.org/project/charts/issues/3389081

Comment: I got the solution - Storage Entities modules was used for graph chart. And need to give to Anonymous users. Cache flushed and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I've mention, I'm using the storage module for storage entities. So need to give the anonymous user permission to this module too.

Giving anonymous user permission solved the issue.

[image]